# Parameters estimation for curve fitting with Python lmfit

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, least-squares, lmfit

I am using Python [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/intro.html) to do least square fit with monthly average data from 2005-2016. I have constructed the function like below:
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blfJB.png)
and the original code shown as below:

```
# t is in fractional years, e.g. 2017+122./365.
def fun(t, a, b, c, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4):
    An=[A1,A2,A3,A4]
    Bn=[B1,B2,B3,B4]
    sum=np.sum([An[i] * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (i + 1) * t+Bn[i]) for i in range(len(An))])
    return a+b*t+c*t*t+sum

mod = Model(fun)
pars = mod.make_params(a=-10, b=0.003, c=0.01, A1=-1., A2=1., A3=1., A4=1., B1=-1., B2=1., B3=1., B4=1.)

result = mod.fit(y, pars, t=t)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(t, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[fitted line and the original data dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFIk.png)
It seems that the Fourier terms didn't work. Therefore, I am curious that how to give a suitable initial estimation on the function parameters such as `A1`, `A2`,`A3`...?

Comment: A note: not a good idea to use `sum` as variable name.

Comment: Moreover, you should provide minimal working example, i.e. at least a complete working code including all your `import`s. A minimal data set would be nice as well.

Comment: Apart from that, `a` can be checked from `mean`. The `B`s are probably best set to zero. `A1` to something like `0.5 * ( max() - min() )`. The other `A`'s to zero. (Assuming that all your data looks similar to what you show in the link), `b` and `c` to zero as well.

Comment: You might try using the scipy module scipy.optimize.differental_evolution to determine the initial parameters, I have an example of using this scipy module to fit a fouble Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments from mikuszefski and James. I made mistakes on the shape of the sum over the Fourier terms. See answer by M Newville. And see the fit plot at https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qE0-_ojL5N4/Wi85OooEJPI/AAAAAAAAGq8/fYxSpqLSzBobOLHWshk16i7AamIVwFH1ACLcBGAs/s320/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-12-12%2Bat%2B10.04.14%2BAM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.sum` does not do what you want it to do.  It will sum your expression to a single scalar value, not an array of the same length as `t`.    That scalar value then collapses your parameters `A1`, ... `B4` onto a single value, and the fit will have no way to determine these values.

I think you want to make a 2D array of shape (4, `len(t)`) and then sum over only the first dimension, leaving an array of `len(t)` that is the sum over the 4 Fourier component.

Try replacing your

```
sum=np.sum([An[i]*np.sin(2*np.pi*(i+1)*t+Bn[i]) for i in range(len(An))])
```

with

```
sum=np.array([An[i]*np.sin(2*np.pi*(i+1)*t+Bn[i]) for i in range(len(An))]).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer! Actually I didn't notice that the shape of the sum terms. 
And it did work as you suggested.   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lmfit-py/u413sR1XYV0